# ChartJS vector maps

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to include some maps in my website but the ChartJS library doesn't have the map I want.
I want to know if this type of vector maps is something easy to find free online or do you have to build from scratch?
ChartJS website isn't clear about that.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've noticed in *vectormap-data/world.js* file map data is an array of objects and each object has a *coordinates* field. It looks like each object corresponds to some country.

You may try to change those *coordinates* and see how this affects the map. Maybe, that will allow you to create you own map data.

Good luck!

Comment: That's true but I managed to find other solution. I found an KML with the Brazil provinces and I used google maps javaScript API.
It's working great!